# Taking user input from browser and printing python function results to browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, cgi

Well, I hope the title is self-explanatory as to what my question is.

I have tried searching this elsewhere and due to my lack of experience and knowledge, I can't seem to find a source that is cohesive and well explains what is going on in whatever is given.

I have a python file, functions.py, which runs some calculations based off of a user's input. The user should see my index.html file, enter the information there, and with the click of a button, my python script should run the proper function with parameters provided by the user.

It's been suggested that I use cgi and/or AJAX/javascript, but I don't very well understand what code needs to be in which files for this to work.

One point that I am uncertain if it will make a difference is that I would like to have multiple buttons on my html file, each of which corresponds to a different function in my python file, each with different parameters.

I appreciate any help but obviously the more details, the better, so I can really understand this for next time and maybe even help someone else out with the same issue!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your web server? What's the whole setup?

Comment: I'm uncertain, because the server is through my school, but I am certain it runs CGI. That's about all I know on that account.

Comment: It might be helpful to ask the IT guys of your school about how to get things setup (where to put your .py files, etc.)